# Генерация sha256sum всех файлов в иерархии директорий

Tags: linux, unix, shell, sha256

Такая структура вложенных директорий, в каждой есть свой файл: `file`, `secret` и `tmp`.

```
# find .
.
./1
./1/file
./2
./2/secret
./3
./3/tmp
```

Хочется сделать одной командой sha256sum для всех файлов.

Выполняю:

```
find . -type f  -exec sha256sum {} \; > SHA256SUM
```

Но почему-то в файл SHA256SUM попадает и сам файл SHA256SUM.

```
# cat SHA256SUM 
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ./1/file
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ./2/secret
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ./3/tmp
a38937c2747b3c26352bc87803471f8a0d98fd96a76c9b7d7252824602a4f47e  ./SHA256SUM
```

Почему? И как сделать так, что бы в одну строчку, и что бы не попадал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно исключить этот файл вот так:

```
find . -type f -not -path "./SHA256SUM" -exec sha256sum {} \; > SHA256SUM
```

Вроде еще можно это сделать с помощью `-prune`, но не помню точно как.

Comment: норм. работает. спасибо.